# Prolog unknown variable on append

Tags: prolog, logic

I've written some Prolog to replace elements in list two with an atom called `empty` if they are contained in list one:

```
replace_build([], _Inv, _Res).

replace_build([A| B], Inv, Res) :-
    replace_build2(A, Inv, Res), replace_build(B, Inv, Res).

replace_build2(_BuildItem, [], _NewInv) :- !.

replace_build2(BuildItem, [BuildItem| T], NewInv) :-
    replace_build2(BuildItem, T, NewInv1),
    append([empty], NewInv1, NewInv).

replace_build2(BuildItem, [H| T], NewInv) :-
    replace_build2(BuildItem, T, NewInv1),
    append([H], NewInv1, NewInv).
```

However, when I run it, I get an unusual anonymous variable (is that the correct terminology?) as per the following example:

```
?- replace_build([item3], [empty, item5, item1, item3, empty], X).
X = [empty, item5, item1, empty, empty|_G467]
```

(Also it resatisfies which I don't want, although hopefully I can work that out!)

Why is the `|_G467` in the resultant list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem one is this clause:

```
replace_build2(_BuildItem, [], _NewInv) :- !.
```

You can fix it by putting a `[]` for `_NewInv`:

```
replace_build2(_BuildItem, [], []) :- !.
```

The problem there is just that you had an uninstantiated variable being appended to:

```
?- replace_build([item3], [empty, item5, item1, item3, empty], X).
X = [empty, item5, item1, empty, empty] ;
X = [empty, item5, item1, item3, empty].
```

The reason you have two answers is because both of the second clauses of `replace_build2` match, which is why you get `empty` and `item3` in there. Prolog will happily unify two variables to the same value, and there's nothing here to stop `BuildItem` and `H` from referring to the same value. You need to explicitly tell Prolog that these are different, so change your final `replace_build2` clause to this:

```
replace_build2(BuildItem, [H| T], NewInv) :-
  BuildItem \= H,
  replace_build2(BuildItem, T, NewInv1),
  append([H], NewInv1, NewInv).
```

Now you only get the solution you want:

```
?- replace_build([item3], [empty, item5, item1, item3, empty], X).
X = [empty, item5, item1, empty, empty] ;
false.
```

You can also use `dif/2` in some Prologs.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a 'list transform' task, with an 'item at once' logic to handle, you can use [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)/N.

Then

```
replace_build(Items, Inv, Res) :-
    maplist(replace_build_item(Inv), Items, Res).

replace_build_item(Inv, Item, Res) :-
    memberchk(Item, Inv) -> Res = empty ; Res = Item.
```

But to learn Prolog, you're on the right track, and Daniel explained well about your problems. It's important to grasp basic list processing tasks!